# How to stream a tar directory/folder that contains other compressed objects in a file structure?

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, compression, streaming

we're trying to stream twitter historical data from [internet archive](https://archive.org/details/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2020-06). We're planning on using [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) that we're familiar with. However, the file structure for the tar file is different from what smart open generally expects, namely:

```
twitter_stream_2020_06_01.tar
  |
  +-06/
    |
    +-01/
      |
      +-10/
         |
         +-29.json.bz2
         +-30.json.bz2
         +-...
```

How would you guys stream this data? This is what I got when I tried to stream it directly:

```py
>>> from smart_open import open
>>> with open('https://archive.org/download/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2020-06/twitter_stream_2020_06_01.tar', 'rb') as f:
...     for x in f:
...             print(x)
...             break # So we only get the first 'line'
...
b'06/01/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000000700\x000001751\x000001751\x0000000000000\x0013665356325\x00006451\x00 5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ustar  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0006/01/19/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000000700\x000001751\x000001751\x0000000000000\x0013665605451\x00006677\x00 5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ustar  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0006/01/19/31.json.bz2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000000600\x000001751\x000001751\x0000010041216\x0013665401444\x00010514\x00 0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ustar  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00BZh91AY&SY\xf7\x89O\xa1\x06\xd2\xdd\xff\x80v\x12\x86\x01\x7f\xff\xff\xfa\xff\xff\xff\xff\xbf\xff\xff\xffa\xdf?}\xf2\xe0x\x05\x9bP\x07\xd1\xd1\xf4\x00\x0e\x8a\x00\x01\xed\xee\x01s(\xad\xb3l\xdb\x15\xa6\x80\x00\x06mZQ\x92Z\x1akG\xb0`4P\x1e\xe3-\x80\x005\xe3\xe3\xb5j\x8e\x008<0\x1eF\x0f\x0e\x00\x00\x02\x80P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>j\xda\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00o\x9epwM|\x07\xbd\xbd`\xc2\\\xf71P\x1fk\xd3\x80\x00\xeb\xd4\xf3\xdc\x1b\xa1\xdcG\x8c\xdc\x13\x07n\x00.{\xd5\xa8\xbe\x02\x80;\xcf\x9b\x8e\x80\x9b\xcf\x83i_n{\xaew;\x98\xf3\xde\x8d\xaa\xa6\xcf9\xaa\xba\x99\x9a\x9ab\x98\xee\xe9\xcbj\x84;\xbb6\xee\xba\xee\x97r\xb8\xd6\xe7\xc5\xd5}\xf0|\x1d\x1dW\xdf^\xf4\xfb\xaf\xbbP")n\xee\xbe\x95O{=\xdeu\xc0|\x00\x00\x00{\x93\xbd\xa3\xad\xf7\xbd\xea\xbdf.\x9c\xdb\xba`\xca\xafn\x8e\x9b\xbd\xc0{\xb6\x9dg\x9do,\xfa\xf8!\xe4\xf9\xc0\x05\xd9\xf7\x8a\x92{q\xcbZ\x147\xb0s\xde\xe7R\'\xb3\x15\xecz\xdc\x92\x8d\xd5\xb0\x92\x86\xd6-\xb6r\xf3g}}\xe4\xfb\xef{\x95x)6\xf2{QU`\xcd\xbe\xba.\xd8%\x9b\x08\xdfs\xa9m\x88\xaa]\xb6\xfb\xba\x0b\xb1\x9a\xf3\xc6\xfb\xbc|\x9e|\xf7\xb6a\xd6\x8d\xb3z\xee\xb6\xd3\xbbRD\xd9\xd1\xca\x85(\x1ae\xb6\x9d\xb0+n\x8e\x15)\xae\xdd\xe5\xf7{g\xc5\xda}\xce\x05\x1f^\x98\x95A\xdb+\xb7]\xd9\x9c\xd9:\xd2;\r\xce\xdbw\x15J\x1bQK\x8c\xe2\x8d\xdd\xe5\xf3\xdf>\xfb\xef[s\xc6\xd9@}\xd9\xf1J\xac\x99\xb3\x11\xb3%\xafww]u\xbd\xde\xf7\xad\xb0\xdd\xce\xad4\x1a\xf6\xc7\x08\xf5\xdd\x8a\xae\xf8\xb7\xb7\xaa\xcey\xdeOf\x9e\xebT*\xa6\xed\xc15\xb4\xee\xd3m\x02\xb7w(\x90\xbb\x18\xb4\xdd\xec\xd7^\xba\xe4\xdew\x9fz\xf9\xaf{\xef<((w\xdf\r\xde\xec"\xfa\xeb\xd7\xb6\xc0n\xcelju\xde\xde\xa1\xed\x95\x1e\xc6\xb7\xbb]-\xef=\xe7\xcf\xba\x8f|\xfa\xde\xde(=#\xb3\xd7\xbdMy\x9a\xa6F\xa9)\x10\xad\x81\xbb\x1a\x97\xb1\x94\x12\xbd\xef;}z\xfa\xbe>\x87w\xa0\x00\x01\xbe\x00\x00\x05\xf7\xdb\x95\x87)\x02\xea`\x0f\xa0\x0e\xedJ+A\xb6\n'
```

Seeing that this is trying to read from a compressed file that's bz2, how would we start working with this?

Here are some ideas that I had for what we can do:

- Download the entire 2GB file
- Run bzip2 compression in memory using some library (maybe [this](https://pymotw.com/2/bz2/) one?)

The issue that I see with this is that I would have to navigate to the file path, and I'm not sure if it's going to work with just removing the first few lines or how it's going to handle multiple files or whatever.

What's the best way to handle this type of streaming problem? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, [that one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html). You can decompress incrementally, avoiding having to have the whole thing in memory at once.

Comment: I'm also working on a project where we're having this issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Eric, it's me, v2thegreat. And yes we did lol, I'll show it to you on Tuesday and post the solution here